# What to use as my default to achieve the correct laravel select where?

Tags: sql, laravel, select, eloquent, where-clause

Please, i'm writing a function and i need guidance

```php
function($file_name='*'){
    File::where('filename',$file_name)->get();
}
```

I want the filename to pull all the filename columns in the database table when file name is not defined, and when it is it should use the value to pull the right data.

My question is, what should i use as default for filename in in the function input to work?

Even if is raw sql i will appreciate

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are missing, your functions name

```php
function getFile($file_name = null){

    $q = File::query();

    if($file_name == null ){
       // Do nothing this will get all files at the end since you haven't applied a where clause.
    }else{
        $q = File::where('filename',$file_name);
    }

    $result = $q->get();

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: what i want to do is not just file name is upto 8 things i want to pass to the function

Comment: i read the question again, looks like you are looking for firstOrCreate function...